# Android: How to deny auto-login in webwiev

Tags: android, facebook, webview

I am building an app where I use a WebView to let the user log in into Facebook. The problem occurs, when the user tries to log out. Then I planned to re-open the WebView. Unfortunately I had saved my credentials before, so the WebView starts to auto-log-in.

As I want other users to test this app on the same device, this is not the desired behaviour.

Has anyone got an idea to solve this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: instead use fb sdk for android

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?